# JVM - Why does YoungGen used heap decrease between gc's?

Tags: java, apache-spark, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm

Below is GCViewer graph of some apache Spark executor:

1. Old gen used heap
2. Young gen used heap
3. GC time
4. The phenomena in question

I try to understand the slope in (4). Why would gc start before the entire young gen heap is used (like previous gcs phases)? And why would it keep  decrease monotonically for ~5 minutes before ramping back up?  I thought this can happen if a very big object is allocated (say, read from io socket), for example. But that's probably wrong since old gen didn't change after that.  I don't really care about this example particularly, but rather just to learn some more about jvm memory management.

[image]

Comment: If GC waited until the entire heap was used what would happen to 1) object allocated during GC and 2) if the GC couldn't clear enough space at that moment in time to continue?

Comment: @BoristheSpider obviously I didn't mean the **entire** heap, just relative to previous phases.

Answer (score 2):

One possible explanation I can think of would be a result of thread-local allocation blocks (TLAB).  To avoid contention on a single pointer to the Eden space being used by multiple threads, each application thread has its own pointer to a block of memory in the Eden space.  When a TLAB is used up a new one is allocated (this can also involve allocating a larger block so disparities between thread allocation rates can be smoothed out).

The implication of this is that often there will be unused space in TLABs when a GC needs to occur (because one thread needs a new TLAB and there isn't enough space for it).  You may get a situation where the amount of space left in TLABs increases due to the allocation rate of other threads.

Since this is the whole of the young generation, it may also be possible that there are objects in the survivor spaces that are getting tenured at a rate that would cause the amount of space being used to decline like this.

Unfortunately, from the data provided it is not possible to give a definitive answer.